# how to trigger your Jquery dialog (pop up window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, dialog, popup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCJ8L.png)

on click of the button with the ID "interaction", the popup should be triggered and shows up, but it doesn't.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Added a simple jsfiddle of your code.  Seems to work.  https://jsfiddle.net/y52g9em0/2/

Comment: @JDC it seems like the parent template i'm extending from is causing the problem, so i just used a custom bootstrap modal instead of creating one with Jquery.